# AEMET OpenData API no devuelve body

Tags: api

Estoy intentando usar la API de Aemet para añadir previsión del tiempo a una de mis apps, pero todas las llamadas me devuelven body vacío.

Según veo en la documentación, esta llamada debería devolver los datos de las últimas 24 horas, pero devuelve un 200 sin cuerpo:

https://opendata.aemet.es/opendata/api/observacion/convencional/todas

Documentación: 
[https://opendata.aemet.es/dist/index.html?#!/observacion-convencional/Datos_de_observación_Tiempo_actual](https://opendata.aemet.es/dist/index.html?#!/observacion-convencional/Datos_de_observaci%C3%B3n_Tiempo_actual)

Además, me gustaría saber donde encontrar los códigos {idema} para todas las ciudades, ya que en esa documentación no aparecen. Por ejemplo para la petición
https://opendata.aemet.es/opendata/api/observacion/convencional/datos/estacion/{idema} que es igual que la anterior pero para una única ciudad.

Saludos y gracias!

Comment: Lo primero que me sale al intentar acceder a la URL que indicas es un aviso: ' La Conexión no es Privada`. Creo que deberías de empezar a buscar por ahí.

Comment: Sí, hay un aviso de que a pesar de ir por https se utiliza un certificado no válido, pero aún así debería dar una respuesta. (Lamentablemente este comportamiento con el https se puede ver en prácticamente todas las webs y APIs de administraciones públicas)

Comment: ¿Estas suministrando la ApiKey? Sin ella no se genera el cuerpo.  Acabo de probar usando Python con una ApiKey válida y se genera la respuesta correctamente, ignorando la comprobación del certificado por supuesto :(. Te doy la razón en cuanto a lo de los certificados en las webs de la Administración, y no es nuevo el problema.... XD

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Necesitas proporcionar una ApiKey válida, de lo contrario te retornará una respuesta correcta (Status 200) pero sin contenido en el cuerpo.

Puedes obtener la ApiKey con validez de 90 dias de forma sencilla  [aquí](https://opendata.aemet.es/centrodedescargas/altaUsuario).

En cuanto a los ids de las estaciones meteorologicas automáticas (idema) no se si existe un listado con todas las existentes a nivel nacional, la Junta de Andalucía por ejemplo si proporciona en su Web una lista con las situadas en la comunidad.

Lo que puedes hacer es obtener la lista parseando el JSON de la respuesta de `/opendata/api/observacion/convencional/todas`.

No se que lenguaje usas para la app pero probando en Python 3.6 se obtiene la respuesta sin problemas:

```
import http.client
import ssl
import json

apyKey='eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9...' #<<< Sustituir por ApiKey válida 

context = ssl.create_default_context()
context.check_hostname = False
context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE
conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("opendata.aemet.es", context = context)



headers = {
    'cache-control': "no-cache"
    }

conn.request("GET", f"/opendata/api/observacion/convencional/todas?api_key={apyKey}", headers=headers, )
res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read().decode('utf-8','ignore')
data = json.loads(data)

conn.request("GET", data['datos'], headers=headers, )
res= conn.getresponse()
datos = res.read().decode('utf-8','ignore')
datos= json.loads(datos)

idemas = {estacion['ubi']:estacion['idema'] for estacion in datos}

print(idemas['GRANADA/AEROPUERTO'])
```

`idemas` es un diccionario que contiene la ubicación y la `idema` de todas las estaciones retornadas por la consulta:

> VANDELLS: 0002I
>   ALFORJA: 0009X
>   REUS/AEROPUERTO: 0016A
>   VALLS:0034X
>   TARRAGONA  FAC. GEOGRAFIA: 0042Y
>   PONTONS: 0061X
>   VILAFRANCA DEL PENEDS: 0066X
>   SITGES-VALLCARCA: 0073X
>   BARCELONA/AEROPUERTO: 0076
>   BERGA  INSTITUTO: 0092X
>   BALSARENY: 0106X
>   PRATS DE LLUANS: 0114X
>   MOI: 0120X
>   MANRESA: 0149X
>   MONTSERRAT: 0158X
>   IGUALADA: 0171X
>   CORBERA  PIC D?AGULLES: 0194D
>   BARCELONA CMT: 0201D
>   ...

Te dejo un [enlace a un Blog](http://climaenmapas.blogspot.com.es/p/usando-aemet-opendata.html) con información sobre el uso de la api OpenData de la AEMET por si te resulta de ayuda.

Comment: Muchas gracias! No había entontrado por ningún sitio donde introducir la api key. El enlace del blog también es muy útil.

Answer (score 0):

Si interesa usar la API con R se puede instalar el paquete climaemet, cargar la librería y una vez solicitada e introducida la API key hay multiples funciones que facilitan el análisis.

Aquí dejo una muestra de mi código y un link de github con información muy completa.

```
##Aemet set up and queries
install.packages("climaemet")
#> Installing package into 'C:/*******4.0'
#> (as 'lib' is unspecified)
#> package 'climaemet' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
#> 
#> The downloaded binary packages are in
#>  C:\Users\perez\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp8s0w7t\downloaded_packages
library(climaemet)
#> Warning: package 'climaemet' was built under R version 4.0.5
#> 
#> Welcome to climaemet (1.0.0.9000)
#> Note that since climaemet (>=1.0.0) the results are provided on tibble format. Run `climaemet_news()` to see the changelog.
#> If you experience any problem open an issue on https://github.com/rOpenSpain/climaemet/issues
#> 
#> 
#> AEMET_API_KEY variable detected on this session.
options(repos = c(
  ropenspain = "https://ropenspain.r-universe.dev",
  CRAN = "https://cloud.r-project.org"
))

api_key="eyJvbGUi****************JLKBlnz5MexoA4"

aemet_api_key(api_key, install = TRUE)
palma_port = "B228"
palma_aero = "B278"
#aemet_stations devuelve información sobre las estaciones meteorológicas
#stations = aemet_stations()
data_daily.p = aemet_daily_clim(palma_port, start = "2018-05-05", end = "2020-03-10")
data_daily.a = aemet_daily_clim(palma_aero, start = "2018-05-05", end = "2020-03-10")
```

Trabajar con esta librería facilita el uso de la API así como la obtención de información sin necesidad de queries complejas.

https://github.com/rOpenSpain/climaemet