# Bajar datos climatológicos de AEMET opendata (mensual)

Tags: python, api

He seguido el código propuesto por FJSevilla [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/63842/aemet-opendata-api-no-devuelve-body), pero no logro obtener otro dato que no sea "nombre, id o Fecha". Es decir si, en el código propuesto, reemplazo "idema" por "tmed", python me devuelve un error como si no pudiera reconocer "tmed".

Dejo mi código:

```py
apyKey='' #<<< Sustituir por ApiKey válida 

context = ssl.create_default_context()
context.check_hostname = False
context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE
conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("opendata.aemet.es", context = context)



headers = {
    'cache-control': "no-cache"
    }

fechaIniStr = "2018-01-01T00:00:00UTC"
fechaFinStr = "2018-01-10T00:00:00UTC"

conn.request("GET", f"/opendata/api/valores/climatologicos/diarios/datos/fechaini/{fechaIniStr}/fechafin/{fechaFinStr}/todasestaciones?api_key={apyKey}", headers=headers, )
res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read().decode('utf-8','ignore')

print(data)

data = json.loads(data)

conn.request("GET", data['datos'], headers=headers, )
res= conn.getresponse()
datos = res.read().decode('utf-8','ignore')
datos= json.loads(datos)

clima_diario = {estacion['nombre']:estacion['tmed'] for estacion in datos}
```

El error que da es:

```
  File "<ipython-input-205-eaa27ee24db4>", line 1, in <dictcomp>
    clima_diario = {estacion['nombre']:estacion['tmed'] for estacion in datos}

KeyError: 'tmed'
```

Asimismo, la variable "datos" está compuesta de la siguiente forma:

```
print(datos)
[{'fecha': '2018-01-01', 'indicativo': '4358X', 'nombre': 'DON BENITO', 'provincia': 'BADAJOZ', 'altitud': '273', 'tmed': '7,7', 'prec': '0,0', 'tmin': '2,0', 'horatmin': '08:30', 'tmax': '13,4', 'horatmax': '14:40', 'dir': '28', 'velmedia': '1,7', 'racha': '8,1', 'horaracha': '14:40', 'sol': '5,5', 'presMax': '1004,5', 'horaPresMax': '10', 'presMin': '1000,7', 'horaPresMin': '02'}, {'fecha': '2018-01-01', 'indicativo': '4220X', 'nombre': 'PUEBLA DE DON RODRIGO', 'provincia': 'CIUDAD REAL', 'altitud': '486', 'tmed': '6,2', 'prec': '0,0', 'tmin': '0,2', 'horatmin': '08:00', 'tmax': '12,3', 'horatmax': '13:30', 'dir': '24', 'velmedia': '1,4', 'racha': '8,9', 'horaracha': '15:20'}, {'fecha': '2018-01-01', 'indicativo': 'C447A', 'nombre': 'TENERIFE NORTE AEROPUERTO', 'provincia': 'STA. CRUZ DE TENERIFE' ...
```

Comment: Que error te da?

Comment: Y por que hacer otra pregunta igual?? Solo espera a que la otra sea reabierta

Comment: Lo siento Christian, no sé cómo es el protocolo. Creí que una vez cerrado ya no se volvía a abrir. El error que me da es:


  File "<ipython-input-205-eaa27ee24db4>", line 1, in <dictcomp>
    clima_diario = {estacion['nombre']:estacion['tmed'] for estacion in datos}

KeyError: 'tmed'

Comment: @SantiagoMosquera StackOverflow no es un foro. O al menos eso me dijeron.

Comment: Muchas gracias @Christian ! Ahí agregué el print

Comment: Lo que pasa es que estas recibiendo do varios diccionarios y no todos tienen la clave `tmed` por eso el error

Comment: Ah! Claro. Entiendo. ¿y hay forma de recuperar todo el data frame, con faltantes?

Comment: Espera a que la otra pregunta se reabra, o elimínala. No dupliques preguntas. Y como te han mencionado más arriba (qué también se menciona en el [tour]): _esto no es un foro, es un sitio de preguntas y respuestas_.

Comment: @SantiagoMosquera 1) no es un DataFrame. 2) Mira mi respuesta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No he utilizado la api que muestras por lo que desconozco cuales son los campos de devuelve o como y porque los devuelve, por tal razón te pedí hacer el `print(datos)` y resulta que te devuelve varios diccionarios y al hacer la comprensión de diccionario `{estacion['nombre']:estacion['tmed'] for estacion in datos}` algunos de tus diccionarios no tienen la llave que especificas `tmed`, funciona con `nombre`, `fecha`, `id` por que estas llaves están en todos los diccionario. Para eso podemos hacer lo siguiente:

Colocar un `if "campo" in datos.keys()` para comprobar que el campo existe como llave.

```py
clima_diario = {estacion['nombre']:estacion['tmed'] for estacion in datos if "tmed" in estacion.keys()}
```

Comment: Excelente. Muchas gracias Christian!